# On what basis are squad points gained during multiplayer gameplay (not counting operations / levels up)?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

Actually, I wonder how many points you get on level-up, and is it a constant, or is it more at higher levels. I always forget to notice it when I lvl up!

But the real question is, what are other means of getting points? I often get "you've received a squad point" notification when I kill someone, capture an objective etc. But, of course, not every time I do that. What's the principle?